# How to add keyboard shortcuts to actions in java

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

I am working on a java image editing applet that has an undo/redo action. How do I add a keyboard shortcut to the undo menu so that when command + z (mac) or ctrl + z (windows) is pressed the undo action is triggered? I have read through action and keybinding java tutorials but I am still confused about how to implement keyboard shortcuts. Thanks

```
public class EditActions {
    
    /** A list of actions for the Edit menu. */
    protected ArrayList<Action> actions;

    /**
     * Create a set of Edit menu actions
     */
    public EditActions() {
        actions = new ArrayList<Action>();
        actions.add(new UndoAction("Undo", null, "Undo",   Integer.valueOf(KeyEvent.VK_Z)));
        actions.add(new RedoAction("Redo", null, "Redo", Integer.valueOf(KeyEvent.VK_Y)));
    }

    /**
     * Create a menu contianing the list of Edit actions. 
     * @return The edit menu UI element.
     */
    public JMenu createMenu() {
        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");

        for (Action action: actions) {
            editMenu.add(new JMenuItem(action));
        }

        return editMenu;
    }

    /**
     * Action to undo an {@link ImageOperation}.
     * @see EditableImage#undo()
     */
    public class UndoAction extends ImageAction {

        /**
         * Create a new undo action.
         * 
         * @param name The name of the action (ignored if null).
         * @param icon An icon to use to represent the action (ignored if null).
         * @param desc A brief description of the action  (ignored if null).
         * @param mnemonic A mnemonic key to use as a shortcut  (ignored if null).
         */
        UndoAction(String name, ImageIcon icon, String desc, Integer mnemonic) {
            super(name, icon, desc, mnemonic);
            
        }

        /**
         * Callback for when the undo action is triggered.
         *
         * This method is called whenever the UndoAction is triggered.
         * It undoes the most recently applied operation.
         * 
         * @param e The event triggering this callback.
         */
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            target.getImage().undo();
            target.repaint();
            target.getParent().revalidate();
        }
    }
```

Comment: _I have read through action and keybinding java tutorials_ Are you referring to [How to Use Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) and [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: Look at the `Action. ACCELERATOR_KEY` property, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70672070/how-to-get-rid-of-repeating-code-in-function/70674791#70674791)

Comment: @Abra yep those are the 2 tutorials I read

Comment: Edit your question and include the code for `ImageAction`.  What ImageAction does with that “mnemonic” argument seems to be crucial to your issue.